# Convert a weird JSON response to an array of simple objects

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to convert the following JSON response to a specific format to be used in a dropdown box:

```
{
"breeds": [
    {
        "name": "Affenpinscher",
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": "/v2/types/dog"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Afghan Hound",
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": "/v2/types/dog"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Airedale Terrier",
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": "/v2/types/dog"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Akbash",
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": "/v2/types/dog"
            }
        }
    },
]}
```

To be used in the dropdown box, the data needs to fit this syntax:

```
items={[
            {
              label: "Baby",
              value: "Baby",
            },
            {
              label: "Young",
              value: "Young",
            },
            {
              label: "Adult",
              value: "Adult",
            },
            {
              label: "Senior",
              value: "Senior",
            },
          ]}
```

where both labels and values would be equal to the one "name" field in the JSON object, i.e.:

```
[{
      label: "Afghan Hound",
      value: "Afghan Hound",
 },
]
```

I've tried seemingly every object and array refactoring tool available in JS, but I don't think I'm doing it correctly. All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple Array `map` should do the trick!

```js
const labels = response.breeds.map(breed => {
  return {
    label: breed.name,
    value: breed.name
  }
})
```

See it in action below:

```js
const response = {
"breeds": [
    {
        "name": "Affenpinscher",
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": "/v2/types/dog"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Afghan Hound",
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": "/v2/types/dog"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Airedale Terrier",
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": "/v2/types/dog"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Akbash",
        "_links": {
            "type": {
                "href": "/v2/types/dog"
            }
        }
    },
]}

const labels = response.breeds.map(breed => {
  return {
    label: breed.name,
    value: breed.name
  }
})

console.log(labels);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered but you might find it useful to implement a function just in case you need to repeat this kind of logic multiple times.

```
const convertJson = (response) => response.breeds.map((breed) => ({ label: breed.name, value: breed.name }));
```

Comment: Great idea! Thanks